# Can I programmatically get the type of traffic google analytics? Ex: Organic, direct or paid

Tags: c#, google-analytics, tracking

How to detect the type of traffic (Organic, direct, paid, ect..)? In the context of asp net, determine from request.

It is possible to do not use the Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] and Request.Url.Query